# Ошибка компиляции программы на GO

Tags: golang

Есть программа на go.

При компиляции выдал ошибку:

```
> go build C:\gopath\cgodownloader.go
can't load package: package :
C:\gopath\cgodownloader.go:4:1: expected 'package', found '<'
C:\gopath\cgodownloader.go:7:19: illegal character literal
```

Comment: Лучше код приложить.

Comment: Не уверен, что получится ответить на этот вопрос, не посмотрев на код.

Answer (score 2):

Я так подозреваю, что вы воспользовались синтаксисом C и написали
название пакета в треугольных скобках.

В Go `import` имеет следующий синтаксис:

```
import "pkgname"
```

Здесь вместо `pkgname` вы указываете имя интересующего вас пакета.

Например:

```
import "fmt"
```